# Add two numbers on MacOS NASM 64bit

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have this code:

```
section .data
x       dw      10
y       dw      10

section .text
        global _main

_main:  xor rax, rax
        mov rax, x
        mov rbx, y
        add rax, rbx
result: nop
exit:   mov rax, 0x2000001      ; System call number for exit = 1
        mov rdi, 0              ; Exit success = 0
        syscall                 ; Invoke the kernel
```

and aim try to compile this:

```
nasm -f macho64 hello.asm
gcc -m64 hello.o -o hello
```

and debug with lldb

```
(lldb) r
Process 74574 launched: './hello' (x86_64)
Process 74574 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000fab hello`result
hello`result:
->  0x100000fab <+0>:  nop

hello`exit:
    0x100000fac <+0>:  movl   $0x2000001, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000001
    0x100000fb1 <+5>:  movl   $0x0, %edi
    0x100000fb6 <+10>: syscall
Target 0: (hello) stopped.
(lldb) register read rax
     rax = 0x0000000200002004
```

I expected in rax is 0x014 but I have 0x0000000200002004, what am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code instruction by instruction and seeing what values are present in the registers during the execution? Why would you expect 10 + (10 >> 7) = 0x14?

Comment: I'm sorry the error in the code I showed, but the essence is the same

Comment: `mov rax, x` tries to move the address of the label (`x`) .into _RAX_. Similar thing with `mov rbx, y`

Comment: Since you have 16-bit values for `x` and `y` (dw) you want to use `movzx rax, word [x]` and `movzx rbx, word [y]` to read them in and zero extend them into the 64-bit registers (movzx willl zero extend and movsx will sign extend). Then you can add the 2 64-bit registers together. There are ways to do it with shorting encoding but that's beyond the scopeof my comment

Comment: @MichaelPetch Had you `movzx eax,word [x]` `movzx ebx,word [y]` in mind for shorter encoding?

Comment: @Kamil.Sm yes wasn't interested in explaining the automatic zero extension of 32-bit destination registers and how it doesn't work if using movsx.